# How can I combine animations in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub, interaction

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with a dropdown menu which will contain some links like:

```
Menu1 | Menu2 | Menu3
-----
sub1_1 | sub2_1 | sub3_1
sub1_2 | sub2_2 | sub3_1
```

So when I click `Menu1` it opens a rectangle with 2 text boxes which will be links. So far I've managed to add an animation to this rectangle and make it fadeIn when `Menu1` is clicked.

The problem is when I try to hide the rectangle and show the one that is under `Menu2`.

In short what I try to say is that if is a way of attaching multiple animations for an object but each one of them to be triggered at some click event or if there is a workaround for this.

**I prefer not using multistate objects.**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I could do it by creating a new rectangle and group it with the `submenu` then put the `fadeOut` animation on the entire group.

A very important thing is to attach the event with `Create button trigger` option available in the `Animation` tab and not directly to the button - for some reason if you try to add the animation to the button from the `Buttons and Forms` section it's not working.

Comment: But this generates a problem when you try to reopen the submenu. So I've ended up using object states :)